# Git and Gitosis configuration

Tags: git, gitosis

I trying from 3 days ago to setup a git and gitosis and i found a simple tutorial

[nfocipher.com....](http://nfocipher.com/index.php?op=ViewArticle&articleId=12&blogId=1)

My problem cames at Step 7 - (On your client) when i trying to get a clone of gitosis-admin and conf it. My bash ask me for password... And it seems to be a problem with rsa key generated. BUT, i followed all the steps untill that..

Where i`m wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Always try to diagnose ssh problems using `ssh -v` first. What happens when you try that?

Comment: It return me that found ssh key on my pc.. in that log...

Comment: Yup, as Greg says, we'll need more info from ssh about what's happening.  If I were to take a quick guess though, I'd guess that you generated a new key pair and forogt to add this new pair either to your keychain or as an IdentityFile in the ~/.ssh/config.
It could also be that it's just asking you for the password to your key, if you set a password on it.

Comment: And ~/.ssh/config isn`t. Not a dir, not a file..

Comment: Hmm, if i type ssh -v it sayd me:

OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008 ... then usage options..

So how to see the log corectly?

Comment: ssh -v gitosis@yourserver
This will print out a lot of information about what's happening in the login process including which keys it attempts to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
[git@host ~]$ ssh -v git@host
OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to host [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/git/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/git/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/git/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: loaded 3 keys
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
The authenticity of host 'host (127.0.0.1)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 77:cf:f8:8a:f8:cf:0a:5f:8c:8e:06:14:04:cb:b9:d3.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'host' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Unknown code krb5 195

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Unknown code krb5 195

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Unknown code krb5 195

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/git/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /home/git/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/git/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
git@host's password:
```

Comment: When you generated your RSA key for git (if you did generate a new one), what did you name it?

Comment: id_rsa.pub as in tutorial said. link to tutorial i posted in first question.

Comment: I think is a problem in /etc/ssh/ssh_config .. 

Here i have:

Host *
        GSSAPIAuthentication yes

and some locale-related environment variables

Comment: This should be an edit to the original question, rather than an answer.